# Getting multiple relationships and children of the same node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to get multiple 'children' nodes by relationship. For example, given the following query:

```
START event=node(4) 
MATCH event-[:photoalbum]->photoalbum-[:coverphoto]->coverphoto 
RETURN event, photoalbum, coverphoto
```

I thought it would be possible to also get the location of an event as follows:

```
START event=node(%i) 
MATCH event-[:photoalbum]->photoalbum-[:coverphoto]->coverphoto, event-[:location]->location 
RETURN event, photoalbum, coverphoto, location
```

However I just get an error saying they were expecting a RETURN type.

I have looked through the [Cypher documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.1/cypher-query-lang.html) but I can't seem to find anything on multiple MATCHes.

Comment: That should work... I've never seen that error about a return type. Can you give us the whole error?

Comment: It turns out I only briefly read and therefore forgot about incoming/outgoing relationships. It just so happens that the location was an incoming relationship so wouldn't fetch. Instead of `-->` or `<--` I am just using `--` so the direction of relationship is generic.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I only briefly read and therefore forgot about incoming/outgoing relationships. It just so happens that the location was an incoming relationship so wouldn't fetch. Instead of --> or <-- I am just using -- so the direction of relationship is generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, it works fine with me

```
START event=node(%i) 
MATCH location<-[:location]-event-[:photoalbum]->photoalbum-[:coverphoto]->coverphoto
RETURN event, photoalbum, coverphoto, location
```